# How can I indent Ruby and Rails code in Vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, indentation

I just wonder if it´s possible to auto indent Rails Code in Vim instead of this:

```
validates :email, :presence => true,
  :format => { :with => email_regex },
  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

to this:

```
validates :email, :presence   => true,
                  :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do this is not actually to use built-in alignment in Vim, but rather the [Align Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) by Dr. Chip, which is used to horizontally align arbitrary symbols in vertical columns.

`1,3Align =>` will align on the `=>`, for example. You can get extremely detailed with the ordering etc by using the `AlignCtrl` function, but the extent of its functionality is likely left to its documentation. `:)`

Comment: Thank´s @sleepynate I figured out it works with the following Commands: `:AlignCtrl Wlp0P1:
:Align :
:AlignCtrl Wlp1P1:
:Align =>`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers.

If anyone needs this too, in [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) this works with:

```
:Tabularize /^[^:]*\zs:/r1c0l0
:Tabularize /^[^=>]*\zs=>/l1
```

If you want to use this in a function in your vimrc:

```
function IndentV()
  Tabularize /^[^:]*\zs:/r1c0l0
  Tabularize /^[^=>]*\zs=>/l1
endfunction
map <Leader>iv :call IndentV()<cr>
```

So you just select text in visual mode an press `\iv` to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I use both the [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) and [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugins.

Align has some nice pre-built alignments, whereas Tabular allows you to design a regex that will be used to match the fields. I find myself using Tabular more these days, but your mileage might vary.